# Why does XCTest run tests twice on 64-bit architectures?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, arm64, gh-unit

I recently setup a unit test suite using the XCTest framework with XCode bots and a dedicated OS X server. I'm noticing that when I run the tests targeting 64-bit architecture (in this case, the iPhone simulator on x86_64), the tests run twice. Why is this? I've attached a screenshot showing the 57 test being run on i386, and 114 tests being run on x86_64 (for a total of 171 tests):
[image]

Comment: Do you have some log output? Specially the two outputs of a single test.

Comment: Does this happen when you create a new, empty project with tests and run a bot for it?

Comment: I have run some Unit Testings on both x86_64 and i386 on my own OS X server. I am having the same number of tests. Could it be there are certain testings/functions inside your app that you are running is just for x86_64? Do you think that it is pretty strange that some tests on x86_64 as shown on your screen shot do not have the method name?

Answer (score 0):

What is "Build Active Architecture Only" (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCHS`) set to in your project?

Setting this to Yes in Debug configuration (the configuration my tests run in) fixed this problem for me.

Comment: ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH, no S at end